# How to Uninstall Version of OpenJdk

Tags: java, terminal, java-11, uninstallation

Removed the jdk in the Terminal using these commands: "sudo rm -fr jdk-17.0.7.jdk" and "sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java".

My terminal keeps showing that I have some version of java, so I am a little confused, I wanna uninstall openjdk completely from my laptop and then get a lower version. Right now I have version "17.0.7" as you can see.

When running "java -version", i get "openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.7+7 (build 17.0.7+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.7+7 (build 17.0.7+7, mixed mode, sharing)
"

Overall I am just trying to get a version of OpenJdk that is under version 11 and use that version instead of 17. I have been trying to find out how to work TMC Beans on Mac for a Course and I realized the reason it hasn't been working is because it only takes a Openjdk version of under 11. Also I need TMC Beans to submit and use the course.

Comment: You very rarely uninstall things by deleting directories. What is your OS? Also please say why you want a "lower version"

Comment: My version for mac?

Comment: OK, I thought it might be Mac but wasn't sure. That's an OS I don't know enough about to help

Comment: Oh I want a lower version for a course, it really isnt that important. I have been trying to find out how to work TMC Beans on Mac and I realized the reason it hasnt been working is because it only takes a openjdk version of under 11. Also I need TMC Beans to submit and use the course.

Comment: Its a Mac Book Air version "10.15.6"

Comment: That op could have nasty knock-on effects. If I were you, I'd probably try to restore to before installation of that JDK with Time Machine, then install the version you wnat

Comment: Which version exactly you are trying to install? Your question is really how to install a specific version of JDK rather than how to delete the newer version. This is an XY Problem as currently asked

Comment: @aled, not exactly. There are now *two* problems, which could potentially compound each other

Comment: Basically Im trying to install a version lower than 11 and only use that specific version. If I ask what version I have on the terminal it should show a version lower than 11.

Comment: You might 'get away with' leaving your partial, broken installation on the system, but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Every time I see my version its still 17 so I don't think anything went broken or wrong.

Comment: Well you started by saying that you force-deleted its entire directory trees, so if it's still working and valid, I'd be surprised (unless your commands failed)